# Buttons in linearlayout appearing vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to Android and I'm trying to dynamically add buttons in my android app, the problem is that they appear vertically, while this should be horizontally.

What I'm getting:

[image]

What I'm expecting (and want):

[image]

**Code I'm using:**

MainActivity.java:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_linearlayout);

    for(int x = 1; x <= 5 ; x++)
    {
        LinearLayout tmpLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        tmpLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        tmpLinearLayout.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
        tmpLinearLayout.getLayoutParams().height = 200;
        ll.addView(tmpLinearLayout); 

        for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
        {

            Button tmpButton = new Button(this);
            tmpButton.setText("nr:" + i +" - " + x);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

            tmpLinearLayout.addView(tmpButton, lp);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout (activity_main.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_linearlayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone explain why it does this/correct me?
Thank you!

Comment: when the android:orientation = "horizontal" in your xml layout, then how it will show vertical view. just change it to vertical.then everything will be resize as vertical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're programmatically setting vertical orientation.-

Replace this line

```
tmpLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

with this one

```
tmpLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

PS: As far as I know, `Horizontal` is the default orientation, so you actually could just delete the orientation line.

Comment: agreed. Seems pretty obvious though

Comment: Now they're all appearing next to each other. Do you have any idea how I can fix it so that the current layout (a 5x5 table) stays? Thanks!

Comment: You want vertical in XML and horizontal in code. Make sure you changed both of them.

Comment: @JessicaSmets use a gridview of buttons with 5 columns

Answer (score 0):

Change the `android:orientation` to `vertical` in your xml layout.